# java.exe in system32 folder not always created

Tags: windows, java-7, java

I have installed java 7 jre on one computer.
When I run it from command line it runs it from c:\windows\system32.

On another computer, the installation did not create java in system32
(only in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7).
Therefor, I have to add it to the path and i am not the admin in this computer.

Why wasnt java.exe in system32 created in both cases?
what is the java in system32 ?
Thanks.

Comment: Subquestion about what is the java.exe win system 32: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES

Comment: Should be in : programmers.stackexchange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you answered your question yourself. You are not an administrator of this computer, so setup cannot create files under `system32`.

BTW instead of copying file to this directory you can just add the real java home path to your `PATH` environment variable. This approach does not require additional permission and allows holding several java environment on the same machine at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 7 security model prevents non-admin users from writing to the system directories.  This is to prevent "normal" users from overwriting or damaging important files for the operating system.